# Q: R for-loop and tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble dataset in R. The tibble Daily.log has 13 variables and 3'924'849 observations. The tibble contains crypto assets data from 2013-12-27 to 2019-01-31. The aim is to figure out, in which crypto assets I would have been invested during the period between 2015-01-01 and 2018-12-31.

#### Variables of the Tibble:

name; date; ranknow; open; high; low; close; volume; market; close_ratio; spread; value; return. name=chr, date=date and all the rest=numeric.

#### The variable name is sorted alphabetically:

Meaning Daily.log[1:1861,] represents the first asset (2013-12-27 to 2019-01-31) whereas Daily.log[1862:3722,] represents the second asset (2013-12-27 to 2019-01-31) and so on...

#### The restrictions regarding an Investment are the following:

Crypto asset must been traded the last 365 days. From those which fullfill this requirement select those 20 with the highest average volume during the past 183 days.

#### For the 2015-01-01, I did this as follows:

```
k     <- 20
names <- Daily.log %>% 
  filter(date<="2014-12-31") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(return)) %>% 
  summarise(nonNAs = sum(!is.na(return))) %>% 
  filter(nonNAs>=365) %>% 
  arrange(desc(nonNAs)) %>% 
  .$Name
names.20150101 <- Daily.log %>% 
  filter(date>="2014-07-02", date<="2014-12-31") %>% 
  filter(name %in% names) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(volume=mean(volume,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(volume)) %>% 
  slice(1:k) %>% 
  .$name
```

However, I have to apply this for each day between 2015-01-01 and 2018-12-31. -> Go forward day by day. The aim is to receive all names in which I ever was invested during this timehorizon. Names in 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03 until 2018-12-31.

Does anyone dealt with such an issue and have a solution to proceed with a for-loop?

Comment: I can't think of a way to efficiently do what you describe, but `top_n` might be an alternative to arrange + slice; and if you use proper date types, you can subtract 183 days, etc (see the lubridate package) if you get stuck using a loop.

Comment: You can probably use [`tsibble`](https://github.com/tidyverts/tsibble) to do these windowed operations a bit easier.